# Wait execution of Box job if dependent Job is in running state and resume execution of box job once dependent job has finished

Tags: bash, autosys

We have a Box Job which is scheduled to run at X time whose execution needs to be waited if another normal Autosys job A is in progress and resume execution of box job once dependent job has finished..Note the dependent job is not Box Job..We have added condition in Box job JILL as follows

`condition:s(Job A)`

However Box Job is not waiting even if dependent job is in progress..Is there any way to handle this scenario through Autosys..Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Since Job B outcome is not considered, irrespective of success or failure. The box job should only start if Job B is not in running stage. For this the appropiate condition would be:

```
condition:n(Job A)
```

here n represent "Not Running"

Comment: it looks like it doesn't resume the execution of Box job if Job A finishes its work..I believe check happens at run time and Box job would simply skip execution of it as Job A was in running state..for our case Box job is scheduled one and we can not afford to skip execution of it